# Time Zone in timeStamp param to Date constructor leads to 'invalid date' error

Tags: javascript, node.js

While trying to create date feeding a timeStamp to the Date() constructor (snippet below) - the first call works but the second call throws ('invalid date') error whenever a time zone is specified - how to correct this?

```
var date1 = new Date('Dec 17, 1995 03:24:00 AM EST'); //<---- THIS WORKS!!!
console.log(date1)
// Sun Dec 17 1995 03:24:00 GMT...

var date2 = new Date('1995-12-17T03:24:00 EST'); //<---- THIS DOES NOT WORK!!!
console.log(date2)
```

Output:

```
> Sun Dec 17 1995 13:54:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
> Invalid Date
> false
> NaN
```

This is not a duplication question as initialization from timeStamp fed to constructor is requested as against the suggested duplicate question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to initialize javascript date to a particular timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141762/how-to-initialize-javascript-date-to-a-particular-timezone)

Comment: I would not say it is a duplicate as @BabyGroot has already initialized javascript date to a particular timezone on the very first line of the code. It's an argument format error that he is facing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are providing the wrong format in the argument.

`new Date('1995-12-17T03:24:00 EST');`

**What's wrong**

The format you are provideing in date constructor is standard called as [ISO_8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). According to standard you can not provide timezone offset like you did.

**Correct way**

If the time being described is one hour ahead of UTC (such as the time in Berlin during the winter), the zone designator would be "+01:00";

`new Date('1995-12-17T03:24:00+01:00');`

If the time being described is one hour behind of UTC, the zone designator would be "+01:00";

`new Date('1995-12-17T03:24:00-01:00');`

Following all refer to same time `"18:30Z", "22:30+04", "1130−0700", and "15:00−03:30".`

Comment: The problem with that is - you would need to calculate the timezone offset additionally and that `new Date('Dec 17, 1995 03:24:00 AM EST');` works

Comment: Yeah then you can use with that but if you provide ISO_8601 you need to follow standards

Answer (score 0):

This code doesn't solve the problem for directly timestamping time-zones but provides an alternative to supporting preferred time-zones as well creating js acceptable time-stamps converting numerical month to month name dynamically. This is just crude solution open to suggestions.

```
function getTZId(zone) {
    var retId = zone;
    if (zone) {
        //placeholder to maintain / add new zone id patterns
        //a word of caution: some timezones are not supported so offset will be required
        var zoneIds = {
            'EST':[/ET/,/EST/,/EAST/,/OTT/],
            'UTC+5:30':[/IST/,/IND/,/GURG/],
            'CST':[/CENTR/,/NA/],
            'UTC':[/UTC/,/GMT/,/ZULU/,/Z/,/GREEN/]
        }
        //default zone id
        var defZnId = 'UTC';
        var fnd = _.findIndex (
            Object.keys( zoneIds ),
            //lookup all zone id's for a match among respective zone patterns till first matching zone id is found
            znId => {
                return (                
                    _.findIndex (
                        zoneIds[znId],
                        //match each zone pattern for this zone id till the first match is found
                        znPtrn=>{
                            return znPtrn.test( zone.toUpperCase() )
                        }
                    ) !== -1
                )
            }
        );
        //return zone id if matching zone id found else return default zone id: 'UTC'
        retId = (fnd!==-1?Object.keys( zoneIds )[fnd]:defZnId);
    }
    return retId;
}

var yr = "2018", mn = "2", dy = "28", hr = "14", min = "05";
var timezone = "EST";

//get date components for current timezone like month names etc
var tmpDt = (new Date(`${yr}-${mn}-${dy}T${hr}:${min}`)).toDateString().match(/^([A-Za-z]+)\s+([A-Za-z]+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)$/i);

//use above code to create appropriate time stamp
return (new Date(`${tmpDt[2]} ${tmpDt[3]}, ${yr} ${hr}:${min}:00 ${getTZId(tmZoneStr)}`));
```